# Storing timed list in Redis

Tags: redis

I have a bunch of IDs I need to store in a Redis list. This is straight forward. The IDs are simply unsigned integers. After a few hours, I need an ID to expire in the list. Currently I don't see a way of doing this as you can only set an expiry time on an entire key, and not an element within a list.

What are some solutions/work arounds for this using Redis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the IDs unique? If so, then you can use a [`SORTED SET`](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) instead of a `LIST` (which is better anyway in this case, regardless of the hack I'm just about to describe).

Then, use a Unix time as the *score* of each item. The items will still not be deleted automatically, but you can run some worker that deletes old items from time to time (use [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to sort for certain ranges), and anyway, in your client code, you can check the score of the item you extract and validate that it has not (logically) expired.